# How do I get ktor testApplication client to not wait for a coroutine job in the call to complete?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, kotlintest

In the `ktor` application I have a route that starts a session for the created resource that launches a job to manage interactions with that session and auto-terminates the session if there are no interactions for a while

```kotlin
// routing
post("/sessions") {
  val sessionName = call.receive<NewSessionRequest>().name
  val session = Sessions.newSession(sessionName) // Companion object that creates a session
  launch {
    var sessionExists = true
    while (sessionExists) {
      sessionExists = withTimeoutOrNull(session.timeToLive) {
        session.lifeChannel.receive()
      } ?: false
    }
    session.close()
    Sessions.remove(session)
  }
  call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Created, sessionName)
}

post("/sessions/{name}") {
  // other call that pings the sessions lifeChannel
}
```

and then some other route that triggers a message to be sent to the `session`'s `lifeChannel` to keep the session alive.

In normal operation this works quite well and the session is kept alive as desired. However, during testing the test waits until the entire launched job completes before continuing.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `user can create room`() = testApplication {
  val response = jsonClient.post("/sessions") {
    contentTupe(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody(NewSessionRequest("sess"))
  }
  assertEquals(HttpStatusCodes.created, response.status)
}
```

Will wait until the job completes and the session terminates before completing the test.

How can I get the testApplication to ignore or work outside of the coroutine context of the application as a normal http call would do with a real ktor app? Is this a bad practice as testing for it is non-intuitive?

## Edit

Adding a simple test I want to have pass

```kotlin
class CoroutineRoutesTest {
    @Test
    fun `how to deal with launched coroutine`() {
        testApplication {
            application {
                routing {
                    get("/launch-job") {
                        val delay = 1.seconds
                        launch {
                            delay(delay)
                        }
                        call.respond("Job lasting for $delay")
                    }
                }
            }
            val response: HttpResponse
            val timing = measureTimeMillis {
                response = client.get("/launch-job")
            }
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
            LoggerFactory.getLogger("CoroutineTest").info("response time: $timing ms")
            assertTrue(timing < 800)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a new coroutine scope for managing interactions with sessions and launch your job under that scope. Since a launched job is unrelated to a Request job, the test won't wait until the launched job completes. Actually, I observe the same behavior with a real server application but for the case that is simpler than yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make your last test pass by launching a job from a different coroutine scope. I'm not sure whether this is the desired behavior or not.

```
@Test
fun `how to deal with launched coroutine`() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    testApplication {
        application {
            routing {
                get("/launch-job") {
                    val delay = 1.seconds
                    scope.launch {
                        delay(delay)
                    }
                    call.respond("Job lasting for $delay")
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I was doing `launch(someContext) { ... }`. I must read more on coroutines to understand the difference on `scope.launch { ... }` v `launch(context) { ... }`. I deleted my comment on your previous comment answer as it was not truthful. Rather I was launching a coroutine with a different context, not scope as I was claiming.